# How do I assign the play button to play only the first object in parse?

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I have two songs on Parse, and I can get them to play using swift, but I want a play/pause button per object. Song 1 should have a play/pause button, Song 2 should have a play/pause button, etc. How would I make each button work for x object in the table view? I have already tried adding parameters to the `AudioPlayer.play()` `AudioPlayer.play(objectId[0])`, but it does not work.

```
    func playit (sender: UIButton!){
    switch(state){
    case 0:
        AudioPlayer.play()
        println("Playing");
        let pauseimage = "pause"
        play.setImage(UIImage(named: pauseimage), forState: .Normal)
        state = 1
        break;
    case 1:
        AudioPlayer.pause()
        println("Paused");
        let playimage = "player"
        play.setImage(UIImage(named:playimage), forState: .Normal)
        state = 0
        break;

    default: break;
    }

}


        var ObjectIDQuery = PFQuery(className: "Songs")
        //find objects in background
        ObjectIDQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({
            //store objects in an array
            (objectsArray: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

            var objectIDs = objectsArray as! [PFObject]
             NSLog("\(objectIDs)")
            //objects being added to idArray
            for i in 0...objectIDs.count-1{
                //add a new element in the array
                self.iDArray.append(objectIDs[i].valueForKey("objectId")as! String)
                //store song name in song array
                self.NameArray.append(objectIDs[i].valueForKey("Name")as! String)
                self.tableView.reloadData()

            }
        })


    }

    //select a certain song from tableview
    func grabSong(){
        var SongQuery = PFQuery(className: "Songs")
        //taking x object from idArray depending on which cell is selected
        SongQuery.getObjectInBackgroundWithId(iDArray[SelectedSongNumber], block: {
            //store object inside pfobject
            (object: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            //take objects grabbed and put in audioplayer
            if let AudioFileURLTemp = object?.objectForKey("File")?.url{
                AudioPlayer = AVPlayer(URL: NSURL(string: AudioFileURLTemp!))
                AudioPlayer.play()

            }
        })
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return iDArray.count

    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as! UITableViewCell

        cell.textLabel?.text = NameArray[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        SelectedSongNumber = indexPath.row
        grabSong()
        }
```

Comment: If each song is a separate `UITableViewCell` in your `UITableView`, have you tried embedding a button in each cell?

Comment: How would I implement a button per cell?

Answer (score 0):

So if each of your songs if currently a `UITableViewCell` inside your `UITableView` you should try embedding each cell with a `UIButton`. First make a custom `UITableViewCell` in a separate file. In my example, I dragged a `UIButton` into my prototype cell in the `Storyboard`, positioning it as I want. Then create a custom `UITableViewCell` in a new file, let's say MyCustomCell.swift. Don't forget to connect your prototype cell in your Storyboard with your custom cell class. Then drag the button from the storyboard in:

```
class MyCustomCell: UITableViewCell{
    @IBOutlet weak var playButton: UIButton!
    //Declare other cell attributes here
    // ......
}
```

Then you can do this in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` function:

```
       override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as! MyCustomCell

            cell.textLabel?.text = NameArray[indexPath.row]

            cell.playButton.layer.setValue(indexPath.row, forKey: "index")
            cell.playButton.addTarget(self, action: "playSong:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
            return cell
        }
```

And inside your `UITableViewController` file create the function:

```
func playSong(sender: UIButton){
   let cellIndex : Int = (sender.layer.valueForKey("index")) as! Int
   //You now have the index of the cell whose play button was pressed so you can do something like
   //arrayOfSongs[cellIndex].play
    self.tableView.reloadData()
  }
```